# Is there punishment for unawareness?

Tags: quran, hadith, punishment, day-of-judgement

Lets say I made a mistake in an obligatory prayer and were unaware or I had a doubt but disregarded it, is my prayer then going to be accepted or on the Day of Judgement will I be punished for having a prayer missed because technically it won't be valid? Also, the same rule for wudu if I made a mistake and ... will I be punished ?

If possible can you use Quran verses or hadith to support answers.

Comment: It is up to Allah to accept our deeds. Whether your prayer is technically valid is a matter of fiqh and to answer a question of this kind the given information is insufficient. The qur'an doesn't tell us how to repair mistakes in our prayers.

Comment: Unintentional mistakes are forgiven isA. But you have a duty to try and raise your knowledge to avoid falling into mistakes without knowing. Doubt is a different story with separate rules.

Comment: What is the rules for doubt then Hosam Aly?